# Can we write an algorithm which gives me two whole numbers X and Y when I want to get a desired fraction F such that F= X/Y?

Tags: algorithm

I am working to prepare a test data set in which I have to check rounding. Suppose I want to check round, round_up and round_down is working correctly at 10 th decimal place or not.

Then

1. if, X=100 and Y = 54 so, X/Y = 1.8518518518**5**18518518518518518519 (test round equidistant)
2. if, X= 10 and Y = 7 so, 1.4285714285**7**14285714285714285714 (test round_up)
3. if, X= 10 and Y = 3 so, 3.3333333333**3**33333333333333333333 (test round_down)

Can we write an algorithm in which

1. input will be rounding mode (round_up, round, round_down) and decimal place I want to round at(in our example 10)
2. output will be X and Y like above?

Comment: Are there any more requirements on `X` and `Y`? Because otherwise you can select `Y=10^{number of digits you need+1}` and easily select `X`.

Comment: This is a problem that's solved in lots of languages on the Rosetta Code site: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Convert_decimal_number_to_rational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the required location is `p` (=10 in your example), then `y=10^p` and then you can choose any `x` you want.

Depending on the language you are using, `p` might be too big for you to do `10^p`, so in the worst case just divide the result from `x/y` by 10, 100 or whatever is necessary.

Comment: 10 is given as an example. My input will be like that 
Give me two whole numbers X and Y, when I divide them, the fraction will have 5 at suppose 6 th place

Comment: Also, taking from your example of x=100 and y=54 giving you 5 in the 10th place, you can just multiply x by 10^(something) and get that            x/y=1851.8518518 **5** 1851

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do like this

```
# n = number of fraction you want to return
def getFraction(a, b, n):
    result = ""

    for i in range(n):
        f = int((a % b) * 10 / b)
        result += str(f)
        a = a * 10 - b * f

    return result

 getFraction(10, 7, 11) # return 42857142857 which 10/7 = 1.42857142857...
```

What I do is like what you have learnt in elementary school on how to do division by pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if the required digit is `d`, then if `d` is not 9, the answer would be `x=d,y=9` regardless of `p` which is the position of the digit. If `d` is 9, then if `p` is odd, the answer is `x=10,y=11` and if `p` is even, `x=1,y=11`. If a trivial answer for `d=0` won't do, the mirror answer for `d=9` is suitable, that is, if `d=0` and `p` is odd, the answer is `x=1,y=11`, and if `p` is even, `x=10,y=11`. A lot shorter than an answer with `y=10^p` and certainly fitting in nearly any architecture.